# Chrome is outputting something different than other browsers/IDE

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

## Problem

I am making a wikipedia viewer for FreeCodeCamp. When I execute my code using Jetbrains Webstorm IDE, I get a total of 10 extra divs created at the end of my search results.

When I do so using JSfiddle, I see the correct results, which should just be the initial 10 search results, and not +10 more empty div containers.

Any idea what's going on?

## Troubleshooting

After some more digging into it, it seems like this is more of a browser issue than an IDE issue. It looks like it's just Chrome that's doing this? I tried on Firefox and IE, and it runs as normal, just like the JSfiddle. I have also tried clearing all cookies and cache on Chrome.

When I open the console log and look at the elements, in Chrome, there are clearly 10 extra empty divs, as shown [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIw9p.png)

But in Firefox, the same code does NOT create the divs, as shown [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4V6fq.png)

Edit: Okay, so in Chrome, if you hit enter, instead of clicking on the search button, it creates the extra divs. But if you click on the search icon, the results appear correctly. Can anyone explain why? Did I place/write the `.keyup()` code block incorrectly?

Here's a picture of said [issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDnm8.png)

Javascript portion:

```
$(function(){
$("#search-bar").keyup(function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode === 13) {
        $(".btn").click();
    }
});
$(".btn").click(function() {
    $("#results").empty();
    var searchTerm = $("#search-bar").val();
    var url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=" + searchTerm + "&utf8=&format=json&origin=*";
    console.log(url);
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            // Create a blank array to store the specific URLs in
            var urlArr = [];
            for (var i=0; i <= data.query.search.length; i++) {
                // Adding the variables for use here
                var headerData = data.query.search[i].title;
                var urlSearchTerm = headerData.replace(/\s/gi, '_');
                var snippetData = data.query.search[i].snippet + "...";
                var createDiv = document.createElement("div");
                var createHeader = document.createElement("h1");
                var createSnippet = document.createElement("p");
                var divId = "div" + i.toString();
                var headerId = "header" + i.toString();
                var snippetId = "snippet" + i.toString();
                var resultUrl = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/";
                urlArr[i] = resultUrl + urlSearchTerm;
                // Create the div element, give it an id
                // Create <h1> element, give it an id
                // Create <p> element, give it an id
                // Give each <div> a class
                createDiv.setAttribute("id", divId);
                createHeader.setAttribute("id", headerId);
                createSnippet.setAttribute("id", snippetId);
                createDiv.setAttribute("class", "each-result");
                // appending <div> elements in the #results id element in body
                // appending <h1> element to the div element
                // appending <p> element to the div element
                document.getElementById("results").appendChild(createDiv);
                document.getElementById(divId).appendChild(createHeader);
                document.getElementById(divId).appendChild(createSnippet);
                // populate json data into <h1> element
                // populate json data into <p> element
                $("#header" + i.toString()).text(headerData);
                $("#snippet" + i.toString()).html(snippetData);
                // create a click event handler that does 2 things
                // 1. Gives each div an element that has a URL in the resultUrl array
                // 2. Opens that url in a new window
                (function(i) {
                    $("#div" + i.toString()).click(function() {
                        window.open(urlArr[i]);
                });
                }(i));



            }
        }
    });

});

$("#random-wiki-button").click(function() {
   window.open("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random");
});

});
```

Actual full code including html/css + JS: [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8mq3y5hv/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try updating chrome?

I would try to change your for loop to `for (var i=0; i < 10; i++) {` that way the increment stops at the 10th item.

*edited.*

Comment: I did check to see if it was up-to-date, and it was. I also found that the issue stems from the difference on clicking on the search button, versus hitting enter once you input the search term. Hitting enter creates more divs, but clicking on the search doesn't. Only on Chrome...so strange.

Comment: You could try instead of ``$(".btn").click(function() {`` make it ``function getResults(){ your click function }`` and use onclick="getResults()" on the search bar HTML and on your #searchbar function as well.